# Why can't I launch Jupyter Notebook from command prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, jupyter-notebook

I install `Python` and `Jupyter` but when I launch Jupyter notebook from cmd with `H:\>jupyter notebook` I get the error that `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I check to see if `Python` and `Jupyter` are installed properly and it looks like they are:

[image]

What should I check or fix to make it work? If it's relevant, I also have Anaconda installed in this computer, but I don't use it because I can't update it myself (workplace computer) and the installed version is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `jupyter notebook` from the Anaconda shell. Otherwise, `python -m jupyter notebook` may work.